# Extending Form Validation in Codeigniter call to a member function on a non-object error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I know this has been asked before, and I've looked through every answer posted, but to no avail. Basically, I am trying to extend the Codeigniter form validation library on a CI2+ project, but every single time I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_errors_array() on a non-object
```

Below is my code:

application/core/CB_Form_validation.php

```
class CB_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{
    function __construct($rules = array()) {
        parent::__construct($rules);
        log_message('debug', "CB_Form_validaiton class initialized");
    }

    public function get_errors_array() {
        return $this->_error_array;
    }
}
```

and then in my ajax file I have the construct etc.

```
public function save(){
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

    }
}
```

and inside that if statement I have tried the following:

```
echo $this->form_validation->get_errors_array();
echo $this->cb_form_validation->get_errors_array();
echo get_errors_array();
```

I have also tried placing the `CB_Form_validation.php` in application/libraries as well. Just as well, I have also tried this in my construct of my ajax controller

```
$this->load->library('CB_Form_validation');
$this->load->library('core/CB_Form_validation');
```

And I have set `CB_` as my custom class prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that to fix this, you should do the following:

1. Move your custom form validation class to the `application/libraries` folder
2. You can keep the construct of your custom class how it is
3. Use `$this->form_validation->method()` to access the function you would like
4. As long as your loading the `form_validation` library, you don't need to perform `$this->load->library('custom_class')` because CI picks up on your custom prefix anyways

Hope this helps someone